# Write j-text utils table to file

Tags: java

I am working on a project which handles orders from customers.

I am using this util to display my data into a table:[j-text utils](https://code.google.com/archive/p/j-text-utils/downloads).
I would like to know if it is possible to write the table as how it would be printed to a file?

This is the display table
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is old question. But just to help others.
You have to use

`TextTable tt = new TextTable(columnNames, data);
 tt.printTable(outputFile, 0);`

where outputFile is object of PrintStream