# Getting exception while printing Resultset with j-text utils' TextTable Class instead of table with ResultSet values

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Trying the below code to print the table from ResultSet in java but getting error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
at dnl.utils.text.table.TextTableRenderer.render(TextTableRenderer.java:42)
at dnl.utils.text.table.TextTable.printTable(TextTable.java:76)
at dnl.utils.text.table.TextTable.printTable(TextTable.java:71)
at autopack.JDBC_Connection.main(JDBC_Connection.java:146)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 4 more
```

Code:

```
for ( int i = 0,j=1; j <= columnsNumber; i++,j++ ) 
{
    ColumnNames[i]=rsmd.getColumnLabel(j);
}
rs.last();
int RowCount=rs.getRow();
rs.beforeFirst();

Object[][] data = new Object[RowCount][columnsNumber];
int i=0;

while(rs.next())
{
for (int j=0; j+1<=columnsNumber; j++) 
{
data[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
}
i++;
}

TextTable tt = new TextTable(ColumnNames, data);
tt.setAddRowNumbering(true);
tt.printTable();
```

Note: Added SOP to print Pass to check where the code is failing or not reaching.
Got the above code example from: [Write j-text utils table to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307221/write-j-text-utils-table-to-file)

Comment: What should the expected output look like? It's really unclear what the code is doing, please provide a verifiable example.

Comment: Along with pass pass, print the value that you are adding to data[i][j] and what is import for TextTable..

Comment: the import is j-text util.. For output and other info please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307221/write-j-text-utils-table-to-file

Comment: Now its working but getting the above exception..